# How do I get the text value of the active tab using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I get the text value of the active tab using JavaScript? I can't modify the code on the page as it is a 3rd party web app. In the example, I would want the value "BASIC INFORMATION" returned. I'm assuming there is some type of way to leverage the tabindex=0 etc. but I don't know how?

[image: Example of the markup]

Thanks!

Comment: Just for reference, tabIndex has to do with the order things get focused when you press tab to cycle through a webpage, nothing to do with any visual tab of sorts

Comment: Please use actual code, instead of an image of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the first child (textNode) of the `.applyNow-active` label:

```js
let activeElement = document.querySelector('.applyNow-active label')
console.log(activeElement.firstChild.textContent.trim())
```

```html
<main class="main-container">
  <div class="progress-step" id="ApplicationProgressBar" style="display:block;">
    <section role="banner">
      <ul aria-label="Application Progressbar" role="list">

        <li id="basic-info" tabindex="0" class="applyNow-active">
          <label>"BASIC INFORMATION" 
          <span class="screen-reader-text">APPLICATION STEP</span>
          </label>
        </li>

        <li id="business-info" tabindex="-1">
          <label>"BUSINESS INFORMATION" 
          <span class="screen-reader-text">APPLICATION STEP</span>
          </label>
        </li>

        <li id="personal-info" tabindex="-1">
          <label>"PERSONAL INFORMATION" 
          <span class="screen-reader-text">APPLICATION STEP</span>
          </label>
        </li>

        <li id="app-results" tabindex="-1"></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`applyNow-active` looks like a good class to use. The challenge here is ignoring the child node.

```
let element = document.querySelector('.applyNow-active label');

let child = element.firstChild;
let texts = [];

while (child) {
    if (child.nodeType == 3) {
        texts.push(child.data);
    }
    child = child.nextSibling;
}

texts.join(""); // this is the text!
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/vo0hperz/

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically determine the

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
var textYouWant = document.querySelector('.applyNow-active>label').firstChild.textContent.trim();
```